Git push,pull on Window keep ask for passpharse although ssh-add agent is running?

I generated ssh key, put public key on my account in <github.com>.
I run ssh-add to add my private key file to ssh-agent.
I checked the agent with Get-Service -Name ssh-agent  and it told
he is running

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent


I checked if i added the file to the ssh-add agent by ssh-add -l and he said he saw
it.
I tried to authentic to git hub with ssh and he say i am good

ssh -T git@github.com
Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

But everytime i tried to do anything to my remote origin on github like push/pull, it keep ask me for the passpharse which i don't understand because i gave it to the ssh-agent when i add my private key file to him. If he saw the file, he is running, then he must use this passpharse for me doesn't he ? If he don't work like that why git still say i am authentic. I'm a newbie btw. Tks for any helps.
Update: I narrowed the problem. It may be on on the way git interact with ssh,shell. When i run ssh -i <mykey> git@github.com, git respond that i am authentication. When i run git pull/push on with GIT-TRACE=1 he said this
trace: start_command: 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe' -c 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed11111 "$@"' 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed11111'-o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack ...

And then git asked for passpharse. This mean somehow the ssh -i work when git called it in shell but the ssh-agent didn't join this process, make ssh ask for passpharse. Maybe because ssh-agent don't allowed to run when git called it in shell. This problerm didn't happend when run ssh -i directly on Powershell terminal by command ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed11111 git@github.com where ssh -i didn't ask for passpharse because the ssh-agent kicked in.

Did you provide a passphrase when creating the ssh key?

Yes i do, i gave the passpharse when generate ssh key. It'd match the passpharse i gave to agent because he can read the private key.

Actually, the only problem i can think to is the ssh-key username on local is using my computer user account name which don't match github username. I tried edit ~/.ssh/config to tell ssh to use my github username for host github.com but no use so far.
